# Line to separate footnote to paragraph

Tags: python-sphinx, reportlab, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Good afternoon.
I am new to using this tool.
Starting to use: sphinx, reportlab, rst.
Ask for your help to know if the line that appears when using a note at the end of the document how? and where? can be removed or changed color.
I searched for "line separator"
I found that there are transitions used characters to separate paragraphs in rst
Example:
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2

The closest thing was to use a transition.
Example:

Paragraph 1

---

Paragraph 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZdJV.png)

Comment: Sorry, but this is unclear. What is "this tool"? Are you referring to Sphinx, reportlab or rst2pdf?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See also GitHub issue https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/1179